# A confusion on the fact that the set of real rational function are not archimedean

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, rational-functions, ordered-fields, real-algebraic-geometry

In the book of *Real algebraic geometry* by Bochnak-Coste-Roy, in page $7$ (and yes, I have stuck on the first page of the book :) ), it is given that

> There is exactly one ordering $\mathbb{R} (X)$ such that $X$ is
>   positive and smaller than any positive real number.If  $$P(X) = a_n
>  X^n + a_{n-1} X^{n-1} + ... + a_k X^k \quad with \quad a_k \not = 0,$$
>   then $P(X) > 0 $ for this ordering iff $a_k > 0$. [...]. Note that with 
>   this ordering the field $\mathbb{R} (X)$ is not arhimedean.It contains
>   infinitely small elements (i.e positive and smaller than 1/n, for
>   every $n \in \mathbb{N}, n \not = 0$)such as X, and also infinitely
>   large elements (i.e bigger than n, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$), such
>   as $1/X$

My question is since the ordering is done by the coefficient of the least non-zero degree term, in the "infinitely small" case;

Let $p(x) = x$, and $g(x) = 1/n$, so we want to show that for any $a\in \mathbb{N},$ $a * p(x) < g(x) \Rightarrow a*p(x) - g(x) < 0$

So, since $$h(x) = a*x - 1/n < 0$$(i.e since -1/n < 0), we have p(x) is infinitely small.

However, in this case any positive constant function would work instead of 1/n, so is there any reason for the choice of 1/n in this case?

**A side question**: Amost all the sources that I have looked orders the set of rational functions with the leading coefficient of the rational function, whereas in this book author chooses the order the set with the coefficient of the least nonzero element, so is there any particular apparent reason why did author has chosen this particular choice ?

Comment: You are right that any positive constant would also work, but they did pick $1/n$ for show that $\Bbb R(X)$ is not Archimedian with respect to this ordering. $(K, <)$ is Archmedian if for all $x \in K$ there is $n \in \Bbb N \subset K$ with $x < n$. I think you have no misunderstanding (so in fact I don't understand what exactly you are asking).